# how to select values that sum up to 60% of the total

Tags: sql, sorting, sum

assume I have a table of this kind:

A B 3 
 C D 1 
 E F 2 
 G H 4

The sum of the last column is 10, and I want the biggest values that sum up to at least 60% of the total value. So, in this case, it will return

G H 4 
 A B 3

It goes up to 70% but if only the 1st value was selected, it will only go up to 40%. Even though there could be a combination that will return exactly 60%, we want to take the largest numbers.

So, I think I know how to sort the values from biggest to smallest and how to sum up all the values, but I don't know how to then take only lines that sum up to 60%.

Comment: This is basically calculating running totals. What RDBMS is this for?

Comment: Do you need a percentage of the total or are you just going for a target number?  If you had 100 different values and you wanted the sum of all records up to but not over a certain number (453 for example) would that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
--save the whole sum into a variable
summa = select sum(val) from sometable;

select * 
  from sometable o 
 where (
        select sum(val) 
          from sometable i 
         where i.val <= o.val
       ) >= 0.6*summa;
```

Comment: Your use of reserved words `table`, `outer` and `inner` make this query very hard to read.

Comment: I think it should be `i.val <= o.val`. Online demo http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/99506/

Comment: Yeah, you're right. And the online demo: I just say wow! thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think this gives you the correct result. Need to work with a temporary table though, not sure if this can be avoided.

```
DECLARE @total bigint

select @total = SUM(value) from SampleTable

select st.*, 
convert(decimal(10,2), (select SUM(value) from SampleTable st2 where st2.Value >= st.Value))/@total as percentage
into #temptable
from sampletable st

select * from #temptable 
where Value >= (select max(Value) from #temptable where percentage >= 0.6)
```

Comment: what's the order by for? You can avoid the temp table by using a CTE, for example.

Comment: the order by is needed since the OP needs the x highest values

Comment: You're right. I should have mentioned: I'm not a SQL expert :-). Removed the order by

Comment: both answers are correct, but he had an online demo, so only thumbs up for you :)
Thanks!